# How to use nextind in a while loop

Tags: julia

nextind doesn't work inside a while loop

It works executing step by step at julia> command line but no within a while loop

```
mezclado = "AαBβ"
tamaño = sizeof(mezclado)
i = 1
while i ≤ tamaño
    print(mezclado[i], " ")
    i = nextind(mezclado, i)
end
```

I expect A α B β
I obtain UndefVarError: i not defined

Comment: I have marked it as a duplicate since it is a common problem and was already answered to several times, but for completeness I have also added an example how you can fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

write

```
i = 1
while i ≤ tamaño
    print(mezclado[i], " ")
    global i = nextind(mezclado, i)
end
```

or

```
let i = 1
    while i ≤ tamaño
        print(mezclado[i], " ")
        i = nextind(mezclado, i)
    end
end
```

to get what you want.

(the problem is not related to `nextind` but to Julia scoping rules in global scope, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope-1 for a detailed explanation). In short: `i` inside a `while` loop is a local variable unless you declare it `global` (the first approach). The second approach (with `let`) creates an enclosing local scope which defines `i` as a local variable and you can update it in a nested local scope.